# Encoding query parameters with UriComponentsBuilder

Tags: java, spring, url-encoding, query-string

I am struggling to understand the behavior of [`UriComponentsBuilder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriComponentsBuilder.html). I want to use it to encode a URL in a query parameter, however it appears to only escape `%` characters, but not other necessary characters such as `&`.

An example of a URL in a query parameter that is not encoded at all:

```
UriComponentsBuilder.fromUri("http://example.com/endpoint")
                    .queryParam("query", "/path?foo=foo&bar=bar")
                    .build();
```

Output: `http://example.com/endpoint?query=/path?foo=foo&bar=bar`

This is not correct, because the unencoded `&` causes `bar=bar` to be interpreted as a query parameter to `/endpoint` instead of `/path`.

However, if I use an input that contains a `%` character::

```
UriComponentsBuilder.fromUri("http://example.com/endpoint")
                    .queryParam("query", "/path?foo=%20bar")
                    .build();
```

Output: `http://example.com/endpoint?query=/path?foo=%2520bar`

The `%` character is escaped.

It seems inconsistent that `UriComponentsBuilder` would automatically escape the `%` characters but not the other reserved characters.

What is the correct process to encode a URL into a query parameter with `UriComponentsBuilder`?

Comment: But, as I understand, `&` is a valid character in URL. Barring certain characters, everything else must be url encoded.

Comment: Did you find a solution?  I am facing a similar problem

Answer (score 14):

In your example the build `UriComponents` object is not encoded or normalised. To ensure that encoding is applied:

1. Encode it yourself by calling [`encode()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriComponentsBuilder.html#encode--) method (see also `normalize()` method):

   ```
   UriComponents u = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl("http://example.com/endpoint")
     .queryParam("query", "/path?foo=foo&bar=bar")
     .build()
     .encode(); 
   // http://example.com/endpoint?query=/path?foo%3Dfoo%26bar%3Dbar
   ```
2. Use `build(true)` method if the parameters used for constructing the `UriComponents` are already encoded

   ```
   UriComponents u = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl("http://example.com/endpoint")
     .queryParam("query", "/path?foo=foo&bar=bar")
     .build(true);
   // IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character '=' for QUERY_PARAM in "/path?foo=foo&bar=bar"
   ```

Under the hood `HierarchicalUriComponents.encode(String)` method performs the actual encoding. After few internal calls it invokes `HierarchicalUriComponents.encodeBytes(byte[], HierarchicalUriComponents.Type)` where `HierarchicalUriComponents.Type` enum controls which characters are allowed in which part of the URL. This check is based on [RFC 3986](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt). In short, Spring has it's own encoding logic for every single part of the URL.

Comment: I'm not understanding the later part of this answer. What will I have to do in order to fix it?

Comment: great. I didn't know `build()`can take an argument to avoid encoding.

Comment: What is the `normalize()` method you referred to? It doesn't exist on `UriComponentsBuilder`. There is one on `UriComponents` but it's not related to encoding.

Answer (score 2):

1. The syntax is incorrect as you are using
   `UriComponentsBuilder.fromUri()` with `String` parameter instead of
   an `URI`. If you want to pass the URL as a `String` use it as :

   ```
     UriComponentsBuilder
     .fromUriString("http://example.com/endpoint")
     .queryParam("query", URLEncoder.encode("/path?foo=%20bar","UTF-8"))
     .build();
   ```
2. `&` is a valid URL character so it will not be encoded but `%` is not that's why it 
   gets decoded to `%25`.

If you want to see how to use the same with `RestTemplate` refer : [RestTemplate.exchange() does not encode '+'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51676060/resttemplate-exchange-does-not-encode/51678215#51678215)